# Click no FAB mas não passar para a nova Intent

Tags: android

Estou pegando o click de uma lista e passando para outra Intent. Porém quando clico no adicionar ele dá erro.

Código;

```
 Button cadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cadastro.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{NOMEDOPROJETO.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                           at br.com.aula.primeirobanco.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Pelo erro que aparece estou tentando passar um Button e ele não consegue fazer o cast para o FAB.
Alguém sabe como posso mudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Você está declarando no XML como FloatingActionButton?

Seu Java deve ficar dessa forma:

```
FloatingActionButton cadastrar = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cadastro.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sim, mano. Pela mor. Era só ter lido um pouco. Lógico que um FAB não é igual a um Button. Depois que fiz a pergunta ai que me toquei. Foi mal. Valeu.

Comment: As vezes acaba confundindo mesmo, afinal a função dos dois é praticamente a mesma...kkkk